# Number of solutions for composite function

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions, iterated-function-system

If $f(x)=4x(1-x)$

The function is defined over $\Bbb{R}$.

Find the number of real solutions of
$$f\circ f\circ f(x)=\frac x3.$$

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, and are having difficulty with or don't understand, so we can better help you to solve whatever you're unsure of. Also, please give some more details of the question, including implicit ones, such as if are we to assume using only real numbers. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period-doubling_bifurcation

Comment: Put $x=\sin^2(\theta).$

Comment: may be $x\in[0,1]$ or $x\in(0,1)$

Answer (score 2):

Writing out the left hand side yields the polynomial
$$f\circ f\circ f=-16384x^8+65536x^7-106496x^6+90112x^5-42240x^4+10752x^3-1344x^2+64x.$$
This is clearly divisible by $-64x$, and dividing this out leaves the remainder
$$256x^7-1024x^6+1664x^5-1408x^4+660x^3-168x^2+21x-1.$$
The rational root test yields factors $x-1$ and $x-\frac{1}{2}$, the latter with multiplicity $2$. Dividing these out leaves
$$64x^4+128x^3+48x^2-16x+1=(8x^2+8x-1)^2,$$
which has the two roots $\frac{1}{4}(2\pm\sqrt{2})$, each with multiplicity $2$. Note that both are in the interval $(0,1$).

This shows that the function $(f\circ f\circ f)(x)$ on the reals equals $0$ precisely at these five points, and that it is tangent to the $x$-axis at the three zeros between $0$ and $1$. This allows you to sketch the graph of $(f\circ f\circ f)(x)$ on some interval containing $[0,1]$, and from this it should be clear how many solutions to $(f\circ f\circ f)(x)=\frac{x}{3}$ there are.

I leave it to you to find the heights of the peaks of $(f\circ f\circ f)(x)$ between its zeros.